# Docker build doesn't delete intermediate image even with '--rm' flag

Tags: docker

I am trying to build react app in docker, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node as build-step
LABEL stage=build-step
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install

COPY . /app
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Using this command:

```
docker build . --rm  -t react-server-manual:0.1
```

This works, but it is creating a few other images that's useless, how do I delete them?

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your build successful?
The intermediate images are deleted only on a successful build. Also,
`--rm` is true by default. So you don't need to specify it. (Although no harm in keeping it)

Comment: those images are useless to you, but not to docker. they are cache layers that can speed up future builds. Unless you have a space issue (`docker system df`) I wouldn't say leave those images alone. Every now and then you can perform `docker system prune` and that will clean your system. Since you are worried about those images, you might also want to try `docker container ls -a` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this `--rm` doesn't remove such intermediate images

You can run

```
docker build . -t react-server-manual:0.1 && \
docker image prune -f --filter label=stage=build-step
```

(or prune as separate command)

Comment: I agree with the answer. One note: as far as I know `--rm` doesn't exist for `docker build`. It exists for `docker run` in order to remove the container once it exits.

Comment: It most definitely *is* an option for `docker build`